# Quality of presudorandom number generator

Tags: statistics, random-variables, random

I have to test the quality of the pseudorandom number generators on the different samples.
I understand that the good way is to select dispersion as a quality metrics.

I'm trying to find dispersion using the following formula:

$$
\mathop{\mathbb{D}}(x) = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}(x^2) -  \mathop{\mathbb{E}}(x)^2
$$

To get mathematical expectation I am using:

$$
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(x) = \frac{1}{l}\sum_1^lx
$$

$$
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(x^2) = \frac{1}{l}\sum_1^lx^2
$$

Are these methods correct? Can I use these approximations of math expectation for the pseudorandom number generator and why?

Comment: "the good way is to select dispersion as a quality metrics": this is a rather short-sighted statement.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, what are the alternatives? I don't have to dive in too deep and therefore dispersion is quite acceptable

Comment: A measure of dispersion doesn't take into account the correlation between values. A non-random and a random sample can have exactly the same dispersion. Take $n$ truly random values and sort them increasingly. Sorting does not change the dispertion at all. But it creates a strong correlation. Also, take any poor random generator and compute its dispersion. Than multiply the output of the generator by the correction factor. That yields the desired dispersion, and the generator will become accepted !?

Comment: Better to simulate something like the coupon collecting problem and see if you get the correct mean. Puzzled as to how for 'too deep' is. Might google Marsaglia's 'Die Hard' battery of benchmark tests a decent generator should pass.

Comment: @BruceET, Yves Daoust, thank you for reply. I will take my time and study it more precisely. Anyway, while talking about dispersion is it the correct way to calculate math expectation? Is it right with to approximate it?

Comment: If you google "testing random number generators" you will find there is a considerable literature on the subject.

Comment: IMO this cascade of comments is not closely related to your question. That's because you have not told us what generator you are vetting nor why you are looking to estimates of $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ as a criterion. I guess this is more a criticism of the question than of the comments.

Comment: @BruceET, the generator is a black box, I don't know what is inside. I know dispersion formula and trying to understand whether I am using it correctly or not

Comment: You say you are using dispersion as a quality metric. Dispersion of what? To see if variance of a sample matches variance of distribution from which it was drawn? Or dispersion in results from different samples? And what 'different samples'? Brief examples might help. What are the $X_i$ and how did you get them? // And whatever the answers to those questions, I join @YvesDaoust in wondering whether something to do with dispersion is the best way to vet a generator. // Not trying to argue. Just trying to make sense of the question.